# Name error context not defined in class based view

Tags: python, django, dbcontext

I'm very confused by this but it does appear to be my issue. I am getting a name error for context here:

```
class ProjectView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project_portal/home.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # <-- name error here
        context['update_category'] = UpdateCategory.objects.all()
        context['update'] = Update.objects.all()
        return context
```

What am I doing wrong here? I thought that:

```
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

was the definition?

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback?

Comment: Take a look at : https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html

Comment: I don't get a traceback it appeared when stepping through the code on vscode.

Comment: @iFunction: but if you trigger the view, did you get an exception? Visual Studio might have screwed it up

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, I did trigger it in the view yes, as I am unable to step through the template tagging like it says, so this was my next attempt.

Comment: @mbieren, thanks for this, I will study this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WillemVanOnsem, you are absolutely correct, it was a mixture of SVCode and django causing the problem. For some reason, django is not completely comfortable with comments in the templates and was getting stuck on a commented out bit of code, I deleted it and it all ran fine.

This is now solved